# php check doesn't reconnect to admin panel

Tags: php

I'm trying to make admin panel, but in login page when username and password are submitted it just redirects me to the php where it is checking the data, it won't reconnect to the admin panel.. Here is the code:
This is where you input username and password (connection and session are included in head of the document):

```
    <header>
<div class="body" style="padding-top: 150px;">
    <div class="border rounded shadow login-center">
        <form action="provjera.php" method="POST" style="padding-top: 32px;">
            <div class="form-group text-center"><img class="img-fluid" style="width: 100px;" src="../assets/img/logo.png"></div>
            <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="ime" style="width: 200px;" placeholder="Korisničko ime"></div>
            <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="sifra" style="width: 200px;" placeholder="Šifra"></div>
            <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center"><input class="btn btn-dark" style="width: 200px;" type="submit"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the "provjera.php" that is checking the data:

```
<?php
session_start();

$konekcija = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','' );
if($konekcija){
    echo "conenction successful";
}else{
    echo "no connection";
}

$baza=mysqli_select_db($konekcija,'hotel');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['ime'];
    $password = $_POST['sifra'];

    $sql = " select * from  korisnik where ime='$username' and sifra='$password' ";
    $query = mysqli_query($konekcija,$sql);

    $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($row == 1){
            echo "login successful";
            $_SESSION['ime'] = $username;
            header('location:panel.php');
        }else{
            echo "login failed";
            header('location:odjava.php');
        }

}


?>
```

Comment: Try setting location as an URL. (more info: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php.php)

Comment: **Warning!** You're wide open to SQL injection attacks. Use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with bound parameters instead of injecting user data directly into your query like that.

Comment: this is for a school project and it is only on localhost

Comment: **Warning!** _Never_ store passwords in plain text! Always hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to generate a secure hash for the password. Then you can verify a password against a hash using [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: It's not only about security. If any of the values you inject into the query contains, for example, a single `'`, your query will break. Knowingly writing insecure code is always a bad idea. If you later on want to write some similar app "for real", you will most likely copy/paste code you already have. And then it can be hard to find and fix all security issues you might have in it, resulting in insecure code out in the wild. That's a pretty common scenario.